# How to format data with both country and year for a regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, data-cleaning

I have several sets of data, with an explanatory variable that I want to use to explain several other dependent variables. The data is over time, and the explanatory variable is currently in the format below (call it explanatory_index)

```
         1900  1901   ... 2000
Country1  327.1 253.5 ... 537.9
Country2  357.3 300.9 ... 510.7
...       ...   ...   ... ...
Country40 225.7 258.2 ... 451.4
```

and the default format for the dependent variables will be in the same format. Let's say I have a dependent variable (call it GDP) that looks like

```
         1900  1901   ... 2000
Country1  18   25     ... 93
Country2  20   15     ... 78
...       ...   ...   ... ...
Country40 4    7      ... 85
```

And then several more with a similar format, say (market_size),etc:

```
         1900  1901   ... 2000
Country1  7    9      ... 25
Country2  9    11     ... 27
...       ...  ...    ... ...
Country40 0    1      ... 8
```

What I want to do is run a linear regression using the explanatory variable (explanatory index) on each variable separately and get the "overall" linear regression.

A basic 
`lm(GDP ~ explanatory_index)` 
just throws errors, as I expected it would, and I don't want to regress each country separately, or each year separately, since the idea is to show that the index has significant explanatory power across countries and across time, and can explain certain elements of growth.

Would I be better off trying to convert the data to look something more like:

```
               Explanatory_Index GDP market_size  
Country1_1900  327.1             18  7
Country1_1901  253.5             25  9
...
Country1_2000  537.91            93  25
...            ...               ... ...
Country40_1900 225.7             4   0
Country40_1901 258.2             7   1
...            ...               ... ...
Country40_2000 451.4             85  8
```

On which I could just run 
`lm(df$GDP, df$explanatory_index)?` or is there a way to do this with the original data format?

I understand the very basics of R, but when it comes to the structure and how R reads things, it doesn't fit my preconceived notions of programming from other languages with for loops. I assume there is some version of lapply used here, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm open to modifying the data format if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: look at `tidyr::gather` and `tidyr::unite`

Comment: Can you help me in following problem too
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58435338/9812604

Answer (score 0):

The last table would be the most suitable for `lm`

You could do something like below. I only did 2 tables. You can extend everything to the amount of tables you have.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df1 %>% gather(year, value = index, -country) %>% 
  unite("country_year", c("country", "year"))

df2 <- df2 %>% gather(year, value = gdp, -country) %>% 
  unite("country_year", c("country", "year"))

# assuming identical number of rows in country_year, otherwise use a different join
total <- inner_join(df1, df2, by ="country_year")

    country_year index gdp
1  Country1_1900 327.1  18
2  Country2_1900 357.3  20
3 Country40_1900 225.7   4
4  Country1_1901 253.5  25
5  Country2_1901 300.9  15
6 Country40_1901 258.2   7
7  Country1_2000 537.9  93
8  Country2_2000 510.7  78
9 Country40_2000 451.4  85
```

example data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("Country1", "Country2", "Country40"), 
                      x1900 = c(327.1, 357.3, 225.7), 
                      x1901 = c(253.5, 300.9, 258.2), 
                      x2000 = c(537.9, 510.7, 451.4)), 
                 .Names = c("country", "1900", "1901", "2000"), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L))


df2 <- structure(list(country = c("Country1", "Country2", "Country40"), 
                      x1900 = c(18, 20, 4), 
                      x1901 = c(25, 15, 7), 
                      x2000 = c(93, 78, 85)), 
                 .Names = c("country", "1900", "1901", "2000"), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```